# Can't display a WSDL for a WCF service hosted in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: wcf

When I launch the application and go to the service page I see...

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe http://localhost:26109/DashboardServices.svc?wsdl
>   You can also access the service description as a single file:
>
> http://localhost:26109/DashboardServices.svc?singleWsdl

But when I click on those links I don't see the WSDL. Instead I just get the same text.

I assume this has something to do with MVC routing, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens when you forget to put [ServiceContract] on the interface.

Comment: It also happens when you *do* add `[ServiceContract`] on the interface.